# Logical error in push operation in stack

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, struct, stack

I am doing insert operation on stack  as an array but my program is crashing on entering the first value.

```
typedef struct Stack
{
  int top;
  int elements[20];
}
stack;
stack *s;

void push(int x)
{
  s->top++;
  if(s->top<=19){
  s->elements[s->top]=x;}
  else
    puts("Overflow");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your present code, it looks like you're using `s` uninitialized. Use of unitialized memory invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in turn *may* cause segmentation fault.

For safeguard from unitisalized `s` , you may want to modify your code like

```
void push(int x)
{
  if (s)         //check if `s` has been initialized.
  {
      s->top++;
      if(s->top<=19)
      {
          s->elements[s->top]=x;
      }
      else
          puts("Overflow");
  }
  else
      //abort, return error or something similar
}
```

---

NOTE:

Apart from the issue in hand here, there is one more hidden issue which will come forth as soon as you fix this issue.

In your `push()` function, you're incrementing the `top` value *unconditionally*. That means, even if the stack is full, your `top` value will increase and later it will cause in errorneous calculations.

You have to move the stack `top` increment part also under the value range checking.

Comment: that check `if (s)` is a bit tricky; it can be user freed `s`-and didn't set to NULL. Hence that check will be OK - actually it will be UB

Comment: @Giorgi Right, but _most_ of the time, adding a _simple_ null check can save you a lot of headache. :-) BTW, do you have any improvement proposal?

Comment: probably tell user to set pointer to NULL after freeing, otherwise that if statement will trigger UB: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704344/why-does-misra-c-state-that-a-copy-of-pointers-can-cause-a-memory-exception/26704747#26704747. Those if statements make sense if you can make sure that the fact that pointer isn't NULL means that pointer is valid - this can be further tricky given on Linux for example malloc may fail and return not null

Comment: @Giorgi I completely agree. The information above is very helpful, but IMHO, a little bit out of context in present scenario. We don't have any idea about the `free()`ing part implementation, do we? Nevertheless, thanks for the useful information. Hope it will help somebody. :-)

Comment: Yes you are right. Also it would not make sense to call `push` on freed `s`; but that check wouldn't save you either. Unless you set it to NULL after freeing. But then that malloc/Linux issue would be a separate issue

Answer (score 1):

It seems you simply defined a pointer of type struct Stack but not allocated the stack itself

```
stack *s;
```

Thus s is equal to NULL. At least you should allocate the stack itself. For example

```
stack *s;

//...
s = malloc( sizeof( struct Stack ) );
```

But in any case there is no any need to define a pointer. You could define the stack itself. For example

```
stack s;
```

Aldo you need to set an initial value of data member top. I think you could initialize it with -1.

Also function insert itself is invalid.

```
void push(int x)
{
  s->top++;
  if(s->top<=19){
  s->elements[s->top]=x;}
  else
    puts("Overflow");
}
```

Each time the function is called it increases data member top even if it points already beyond the array. The valid function could look like

```
void push(int x)
{
   if ( s->top + 1 < 20)
   {
      s->elements[++s->top] = x;
   }
   else
   [
       puts("Overflow");
   }
}
```