# Can I still call free() on a variable that had a second malloc() call on it?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I was wondering if a malloc() call is tied to its initial variable that you assign malloc() to at all, when it comes to how the system frees the memory.

For example, can I do the following:

```
void * ptr1 = malloc(50);
void * ptr2 = ptr1;
ptr1 = malloc(25);
free(ptr2);
```

I was intending to free the memory that was *initially* assigned to ptr1, but later free it by another pointer.

Comment: You must free every block that you malloc. It doesn't matter who's currently pointing to the block. You have successfully freed the 50-byte block here, but your 25-byte block is left dangling.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Must?

Comment: Well, leaving reachable blocks at exit is not a problem, but it is evidence of sloppiness.

Comment: Misunderstanding: you don't `free` a *variable*, you `free` some memory zone previously obtanined by `malloc`, and it is a a *pointer value* (which could be kept in *several* variables of your C source code or none of them)

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: One exception is in large applications where all desired context wind-down has been performed and system performance is valuable. Then there is no point in doing in-process bookkeeping that will just be wiped away when the process terminates. Of course,managing such “exit unclean” behavior is itself a challenge, since you do not want to forget allocated memory when merely cleaning up subtasks within the process rather than finally exiting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's walk through this step-by-step (`UNDEF` means that we don't know what a value is; `valid` means a pointer is safe to use):

```
void *ptr1, *ptr2;    /* ptr1=UNDEF (invalid), ptr2=UNDEF (invalid) */
ptr1 = malloc(50);    /* ptr1=0xAAA (valid),   ptr2=UNDEF (invalid) */
ptr2 = ptr1;          /* ptr1=0xAAA (valid),   ptr2=0xAAA (valid)   */
ptr1 = malloc(25);    /* ptr1=0xBBB (valid),   ptr2=0xAAA (valid)   */
free(ptr2);           /* ptr1=0xBBB (valid),   ptr2=UNDEF (invalid) */
```

`free()` doesn't know which *if any* variable the pointer it's passed is stored in; it isn't guaranteed to (but also isn't guaranteed *not* to) update or interact with the variables in any way. All that effectively changes from an application developer's perspective is whether it's safe to actually *use* that pointer, or any other references into the block of memory allocated during the `malloc()` call that returned it.

<sub>As mentioned by [@M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/m-m) [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52195022/can-i-still-call-free-on-a-variable-that-had-a-second-malloc-call-on-it/52195059?noredirect=1#comment91341372_52195059), the C language specification is explicit that the value of a pointer to a deallocated object is undefined, and the compiler is permitted to modify it in any way; see [Why does MISRA C state that a copy of pointers can cause a memory exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704344/why-does-misra-c-state-that-a-copy-of-pointers-can-cause-a-memory-exception) for further discussion.</sub>

Comment: C11 6.2.4/2 " The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when
the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime." . 7.22.3/1 says that the lifetime of a dynamically allocated object ends when it is deallocated, and 7.22.3.3 says that `free` causes the object to be deallocated.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes

Longer answer:

You are not calling free "on the variable", but on the *value* stored in the variable.

To better understand what is going on, it may be better to think of memory as a big array of bytes, and visualizing a pointer as a numeric index into that array. And on most architectures you are likely to encounter, this is actually what is going on behind the scenes.

When you do

```
void * ptr1 = malloc(50);
```

`malloc` is reserving a block of 50 bytes and returning a pointer to that block. That pointer is nothing more than a numeric index telling us where in memory the reserved block starts.

In theory we could (on some architectures) write

```
int ptr1 = (int)malloc(50);
```

The reasons we are not doing it, are:

1. `sizeof(int)` may not be large enough to hold a pointer
2. `void *` tells the compiler that the numeric value stored in `ptr1` should be treated as a memory address.

If we continue looking at your code:

```
void * ptr2 = ptr1;
```

There is nothing magical happening here. The "numeric value" stored in `ptr1` is copied into `ptr2`, just as if `ptr1` and `ptr2` were normal integer variables.

```
ptr1 = malloc(25);
```

Here you overwrite the content of `ptr1` with a new "numeric value", but the old value 
still exist as a copy in `ptr2`.

```
free(ptr2);
```

Here you call `free` with the value stored in `ptr2`. This is the value returned by `malloc(50)`. `free` does not care which variable is holding that value/address. It only cares that the value/address points to the first byte of a block of memory that was reserved with `malloc`.

In theory, if you knew that `malloc(50)` returned the value 0xb00b1e5 you could do

```
free((void *) 0xb00b1e5);
```

But you can't safely predict what `malloc` is going to return, so don't do that.