# Correct usage of free() function in C

Tags: c, pointers, buffer, free

I am new in C programming language so can you tell me if this is correct way to do.

for example: 
program points on buffer and i use that `pointer` as parameter in `free()` function. So, what problems can this function cause ?

Comment: If you give a pointer to `free` that was not a pointer returned by `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`, Then the code exhibits Undefined Behavior

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should call free **only** on pointers which have been assigned memory returned by `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`.

```
char* ptr = malloc(10); 

// use memory pointed by ptr 
// e.g., strcpy(ptr,"hello");

free(ptr); // free memory pointed by ptr when you don't need it anymore
```

Things to keep in mind:

- Never free memory twice. This can happen for example if you call `free` on `ptr` twice and value of `ptr` wasn't changed since first call to `free`. Or you have two (or more) different pointers pointing to same memory: if you call free on one, you are not allowed to call `free` on other pointers now too.
- When you free a pointer you are not even allowed to [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26073919/3963067) its value; e.g., `if (ptr)` not allowed after freeing unless you initialize `ptr` to a new value
- You should not dereference freed pointer
- Passing null pointer to `free` is fine, no operation is performed.

Answer (score 2):

Think that the computer has a whole bunch of memory not (yet) used by your program. Now you need some more memory and you ask your computer to give you some more (for example, a large buffer). Once you are done with it, you want to return it to the computer.

This memory is called the heap. You ask for memory by calling `malloc()` and you return it by calling `free()`;

```
char *buffer;
buffer = malloc(512);           // ask for 512 bytes of memory
if (buffer==NULL) return -1;   // if no more memory available
...
free(buffer);                 // return the memory again
```

Answer (score 2):

`free()` function is used to deallocate memory used by one program and move it back to available memory area so that other operating system processes can use that memory location. Also `free` function takes any type of pointer that points to that memory location. 
For example:

```
int a = 10;  // suppose 2 byte is allocated ie location 1000 and 1001
```

Now this 2 byte of memory belongs to specific problem; hence OS will not give this memory location to another process (memory is now allocated memory not available memory)

```
 int *ptr =&a;
 /*ptr is pointer variable pointing to 1000  
 as it is int pointer therefore ptr++ will move pointer to 1002*/
```

Now if we do `free(ptr)`, it will check the pointer type and depending on type free function deallocate memory in this case 2 bytes starting from 1000.

Now interesting point is your data will be there until OS allocates this memory to some other process and that process overwrites it.

Also `ptr` is pointing to 1000 even after `free()` function but that memory location does not belong to our program hence `ptr` pointer has given new name `DANGLING POINTER`.

`*ptr` may or may not give the same value therefore it is better to make `ptr =null`.

Answer (score -1):

From the [man page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) of `free()` function:

> The  `free()` function frees the memory space pointed to by a pointer `ptr` which must have been returned by a pre‐
>          vious call to `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`.  Otherwise, or if `free(ptr)`  has  already  been  called
>          before, undefined behavior occurs.  If `ptr` is `NULL`, no operation is performed.

You have to use the `free()` function when you are allocating the memory dynamically.

If you are using that as a static variable then it may lead to unintended behavior.

---

```
 char *c=malloc(100);//allocating the 100 bytes of memory for a pointer variable c.
```

Here after usage of that varaible you can free that allocated memory,

```
 free(c);
```

If you are declared a variable like this,

```
char c= malloc(100);// It is illegeal. And c will have a memory in stack.
```

If you free this variable,

```
free(c);//it will lead to system crash. Because your freeing the memory which is in  stack memory.
```

Comment: can it lead to spatial memory safety or temporal memory safety errors ?

Comment: ... What? `char c = malloc(100)` allocate 100 bytes on the **heap**, convert the pointer to a `char`, and then store it to `c`. Call to `free(c)` will convert `c` (a char) to a pointer, and then try to free it, which will lead to system crash because (most of the time) converting a pointer to a `char` and back will change its value and make it an invalid pointer.