# How to free memory pointed to by two pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers, free

Assume I dynamically allocate memory by creating the pointer p1:

```
int *p1 = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
```

Then I create a second pointer (p2) and make it point to the same block of memory:

```
int* p2; 
p2 = p1;
```

Then I want to return the memory block back to the heap, so I give the following command:

```
free(p1);
```

My question is this: is the block of memory actually free now or is it still occupied because p2 is still pointing to it (i.e. blocking it)?

Comment: C does not employ *reference counts* like some languages do, so if you `free` memory it can be reused, regardless of how many pointers are pointing at it.  That makes C much faster than other languages - and more dangerous as well.

Answer (score 4):

> My question is this: is the block of memory actually free now or is it
>   still occupied because p2 is still pointing to it (i.e. blocking it)?

No, it has been freed.

Moreover you should be careful in such cases to not delete the memory **twice** (e.g. first via `p1` then via `p2`) - otherwise you will trigger undefined behavior.

Actually this is also useful (C11):

> The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points
>   to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.

And using indeterminate memory is a bad idea.
So after freeing the memory even stuff like this is a bad idea:

```
free(p1);
if(p2 == NULL) // oops. don't do this
  doSmth();
```

Some more details are in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073842/is-the-compiler-allowed-to-recycle-freed-pointer-variables/26073919#26073919).

Answer (score 2):

Once it's freed it's freed.

What you have left is a *dangling pointer* which you can no longer de-reference, or do anything with in fact.

Comment: There are two dangling pointers

Comment: True - I was meaning p2 is dangling (and the rest..)