# Pointer to Pointer null C

Tags: c

I have a question about a double pointer in C.
For example:

```
int** point = malloc(sizeof(int**));
int* point2 = malloc(sizeof(int*));
*point2 = 5;
*point = point2;
free(point2);
printf("%d", *point);
```

My question is, if I have a double pointer pointing to another pointer (point2) and I make a free on (point2), the double pointer (point) is going to point to a memory address that has nothing.
So I should do * point = NULL?

Comment: yes, that could be a good idea to avoid keeping an invalid pointer ref. Note that you don't need to use malloc for those cases.

Comment: `int* point2 = malloc(sizeof(int*));` point2 is an integer pointer; it should point to an int.  So, you should allocate `sizeof(int)`, or `sizeof *point2`

Comment: `int* point = malloc(sizeof(int))` this is what @wildplasser means, I think

Comment: Your mallocs are indeed wrong. Do instead `int **point = malloc(sizeof *point)` and `int *point2 = malloc(sizeof *point2)` to avoid these errors.

Comment: Both mean `int** point = malloc(sizeof(int**));` is only correct by mistake and `int* point2 = malloc(sizeof(int*));` allocates storage for a pointer instead of an `int`. Perhaps `int **point = malloc (sizeof *point);` and `int *point2 = malloc (sizeof *point2);`

Comment: I suggest avoiding the term "double pointer" unless you're talking about the type `double*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you don't have to assign `NULL` to `*point`. However, it is a very good idea to do it anyway, because it helps you distinguish valid pointers from invalid when you debug your program.

> the double pointer (`point`) is going to point to a memory address that has nothing.

Memory always has something in it. However, it's not always under your control, so it may not be legal to read its content.

For instance, when you free `point2`, the value stored in `point` is not going to disappear. However, it would become illegal to use that value, as it becomes indeterminate.

Comment: [... UB to *use* the value as it becomes indeterminate...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073842/is-the-compiler-allowed-to-recycle-freed-pointer-variables)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Edited. Thanks!